# How do I initialize a valarray from a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, valarray

Is it ok/safe/good practice to write the following in order to fill a valarray with the
content of a vector?

```
vector<int> myVect = {2,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}; // Any vector
valarray<int> myVala ( &(myVect[0]), myVect.size() );
//Edit: as suggested by Xeo, this code looks much cleaner (C++11)
valarray<int> myVala ( myVect.data(), myVect.size() );
```

It seems to work fine but I would like to be sure it works on any case.

Comment: These days, I would question whether it is good practice to use `valarray` at all. It's the black sheep of the standard library.

Comment: Why is that? I plan to use them for selection of subsets with masks and slices. I'm not familiar with this structure but it seems useful at first sight.

Comment: It just never got popular. Most implementations are actually poorly optimized, which defeats the point of using it. It's a bit of a chicken-and-egg situation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. The contents of vector are guaranteed to be contiguous (see `[vector.overview], §1` in C++ standard).

Note that since C++11, you can initialize `valarray` using initializer list directly.

Comment: A bit better would be (besides init-list, say if the data came from elsewhere): `std::valarray<int> vla(vec.data(), vec.size())`

Comment: This is indeed much more readable using .data(), I edited my message to include this notation.