# Why does std::valarray not have a constructor taking a pair of iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, valarray

Question comes from my off-the-top-of-my-head answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249882/vararray-initialization-from-a-vector) (which I have deleted cause, well, `std::valarray` has no constructor taking a pair of iterators...).

The question is: why?

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but I think valarray was in standard lib since before SGI's STL (which introduced iterators) was incorporated and nobody bothered to update valarray.

Comment: Because nobody ever really cared about `valarray`; it got into the standard somehow and pretty much nobody ever looked at it again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602451/c-valarray-vs-vector